# Python 2D plots as 3D (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Python plot in Matplotlib: I have a number of samples taken daily at the same time which shows a change in measurement (of something). This may be shown as a 2D plot (below left), but as the sample number increases I'd like to display this data as a 3D plot which is stacked (below right image) - this image is for illustration only.

For a starting point my code is below, how may I achieve this?

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt


t  = np.arange(1024)*1e-6
y1 = np.sin(t*2e3*np.pi) 
y2 = 0.5*y1
y3 = 0.25*y1

plt.plot(t,y1,'k-', label='12/03/14')
plt.plot(t,y2,'r-', label='13/03/14')
plt.plot(t,y3,'b-', label='14/03/14')
plt.xlabel('Time/sample no.')
plt.ylabel('Pk-pk level (arbitrary units)')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Check out the 3d capabilities of matplotlib package: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Comment: There are a few related questions: [Python plotting 2d data on to 3d axes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23507217/1804173), and [Plotting a series of 2D plots projected in 3D in a perspectival way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34099518/1804173)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would it be something like this?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

zs = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
t  = np.arange(1024)*1e-6
ones = np.ones(1024)
y1 = np.sin(t*2e3*np.pi) 
y2 = 0.5*y1
y3 = 0.25*y1

verts=[list(zip(t, y1)), list(zip(t, y2)), list(zip(t, y3))]


poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors = ['r','g','b'])
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1024e-6)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 3)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(-1, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]