# Flat surfaces in matplotlib 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I am trying to create a 3D plot with matplotlib, which represents the outer boundary of a specific domain. This boundary consists of an upper and lower surface, which is easy to visualize using the `plot_surface` method. My problem is to visualize the four flat surfaces which are parallel to the xz- and yz-planes (see attached image below). Since these surfaces also limit the domain I want them to be colored slightly transparent. My question is, how can I achieve this? A minimal working example for the upper and lower boundaries as well as an image which illustrates the desired outcome is attached below. Thank's for you kind help in advance!

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Values for g11up and g11dw
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)

# Meshgrid
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
Z = 2 - (X**2 + Y**2)

# Create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$y$')
ax.set_zlabel(r'$z$')

# Plot the upper surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, -Z, cmap=cm.Blues, vmin=-2*Z.max(), vmax=Z.max(),
                alpha=0.9, linewidth=0)

# Plot the lower surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.Blues, vmin=-2*Z.max(), vmax=Z.max(),
                alpha=0.9, linewidth=0)

# Plot edges
z = 1-x**2
for sign in [1, -1]:
    ax.plot(x, np.ones(len(x)), sign*z, color='k', lw=1, zorder=3)
    ax.plot(x, -np.ones(len(x)), sign*z, color='k', lw=1, zorder=4)
    ax.plot(np.ones(len(x)), x, sign*z, color='k', lw=1, zorder=4)
    ax.plot(-np.ones(len(x)), x, sign*z, color='k', lw=1, zorder=3)

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: this appears to be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36738573/7042795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection # New import

# Values for g11up and g11dw
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)

# Meshgrid
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
Z = 2 - (X**2 + Y**2)

# Create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$y$')
ax.set_zlabel(r'$z$')

# Plot the upper surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, -Z, cmap=cm.Blues, vmin=-2*Z.max(), vmax=Z.max(),
                alpha=0.9, linewidth=0)

# Plot the lower surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.Blues, vmin=-2*Z.max(), vmax=Z.max(),
                alpha=0.9, linewidth=0)

# Plot edges
z = 1-x**2
for sign in [1, -1]:
    ax.plot(x, np.ones(len(x)), sign*z, color='k', lw=1, zorder=3)
    ax.plot(x, -np.ones(len(x)), sign*z, color='k', lw=1, zorder=4)
    ax.plot(np.ones(len(x)), x, sign*z, color='k', lw=1, zorder=4)
    ax.plot(-np.ones(len(x)), x, sign*z, color='k', lw=1, zorder=3)

# Plot faces
for sign in [1,-1]:
    xyz_upper = np.stack((x,sign*np.ones(x.shape), z)).T
    xyz_lower = np.stack((x,sign*np.ones(x.shape),-z)).T[::-1]
    xyz = np.concatenate((xyz_upper,xyz_lower))
    verts = [ ( xyz[i,0], xyz[i,1], xyz[i,2] ) for i in range(xyz.shape[0])  ]
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([verts], alpha=0.5, facecolor='orange'))

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

There must be a way of passing the numpy array straight to `Poly3DCollection` without converting it into a list of tuples, but I didn't look for it.

This is the result:

[image]

Obviously I went for orange, and I only drew the two faces normal to the y-axis, but extending it to the other sides is straight forward.

My answer is inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36738573/7042795).
When changing the color, you may run into [this bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10237/).