# How to highlight area between 3D lines with texture in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to fill between two curves in a 3D plot in matplotlib. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737053/mplot3d-fill-between-extends-over-axis-limits) to do that. But I want to use a texture for filling rather than a single color. I very much appreciate any help. I used the following syntax but it did not work:

```
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([verts],facecolor="none", hatch="x", edgecolor="orange"))
```

In the original code is and has only color as an argument:

```
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([verts],color='orange'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the facecolor to none is returning an error there. It might be a bug but the [workaround](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18020) is to set `facecolor=(0, 0, 0, 0)`:

```
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([verts],facecolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), hatch="x", edgecolor="orange"))
```

Comment: Thanks a alot for your help. I do appreciate it. Do you know any way if I can change the color of polygon with depth? Something like making a depth gradient from top to base of the polygon. Like a Red on top which change to red in the base.