# Intersect several 2-d subplot in MatPlotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, graph-visualization

Familar with Matplotlib and Basemap, but I haven't noticed that some one has tried to plot intersected figure to visualize multi-dimension data.

Here is an  practical scene:  Satellite data now can capture the information of atmosphere in 3-d dimension which contain the spatial distribution in several vertical level.

[image]

The example figure here contain several subplots:

(1) Vertical profile of dust extinction coefficient from calipso satellite data.        (2) The average profile for each slice of (1)
(3) The background figure represent the ground-level wind field of East Asia.
(4) Some purple streamline(look carefully) which pass through each slice       represent the air mass trajectory.

The figure here represent essential information in one frame.

The Matplotlib and Basemap can help me to generate each subplot. Is there any useful tools or python package can organize all these elements into one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2D plots as 3D (Matplotlib)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412813/python-2d-plots-as-3d-matplotlib)